# Como realizar una búsqueda avanzada con scopequery

Tags: php, mysql, html5, sql-server, laravel-5

**Se desea poder buscar por un cargo en especifico, donde al realizar la búsqueda como de Comisión de Coro aparezcan todos los miembros que pertenezcan a ese cargo**.

El codigo de la vista:

```
@foreach($miembros as $member)

                {{$member->mNombre}}
                {{$member->mApellido}}
                {{$member->mSector}}
                {{$member->etapa->eTipo}}
                @if(empty($member->formaciones->fTipo))

                @else
               {{$member->formaciones->fTipo}}
               @endif

                @foreach($member->cargos as $cargo)

                        {{$cargo->cTipo}}

                  @endforeach

            @endforeach
```

Se ha utilizado el segundo foreach para los cargos con la idea de que la vista los cargos de cada miembro se muestren de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se tiene una tabla miembros parroquiales y cargos, con relación de muchos a muchos entre ellas. La tabla intermedia tiene el nombre: cargo_miembro_parroquia

En el controlador se tiene lo siguiente.

```
public function filtros(Request $request){

   $sector = $request->input('sector');
  $forma = $request->formacion_id;
  $etapas = Etapa::all();
  $formacion = Formacion::all();
  $etapa = $request->etapa_id;
  $cargo = Cargo::all(); 
  $m_cargo = $request->car;
    $miembros = Miembro_Parroquial::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->sector($sector)->etapa($etapa)->formacion($forma)->get();

    return view('miembro.member_index', compact('etapas', 'formacion', 'miembros', 'cargo')); 
}
```

Los SCOPEQUERY se han reliazado de la siguiente manera:

```
public function scopeSector($query, $sector){

    if($sector){

        return $query->where('mSector', 'LIKE', "%$sector%");
    } 
}

public function scopeEtapa($query, $etapa){

    if($etapa){

        return $query->where('etapa_id', 'LIKE', "%$etapa%");
    }
}

public function scopeFormacion($query, $forma){

    if($forma){
        return $query->where('formacion_id', 'LIKE', "%$forma%");

    }
}

public function scopeCargo($query, $cargo){


}
```

Si tienen una idea de como realizar el scopequery para cargos en relacion de muchos a muchos, seria de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo ya la relación definida en el modelo `Miembro_Parroquial` lo que deberías hacer es usar la función `with` de la siguiente manera:

```
$m_cargo = $request->car;
$miembros = Miembro_Parroquial::with(['cargos'=>function($query)use($m_cargo){
    $query->where("cTipo",$m_cargo);//puedes añadir mas where para la tabla cargo aqui
}])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->sector($sector)->etapa($etapa)->formacion($forma)->get();
```

y para recorrerlo harías lo mismo que lo que tienes en tu pregunta;

Comment: Hola, hice lo que me recomendo pero no se el porque al ejecutar la busqueda lo que hace es limpiar los cargos que tiene cada miembro. Si tienes alguna otra idea seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para el scope que necesitas en cargos, puedes usar esto en tu modelo

```
public function scopeCargo($query, $m_cargo){
    return $query->whereHas('cargos', function($query2) use($m_cargo){
        $query2->where('cargos.id', 'LIKE', "%$m_cargo%");
    });

}
```

en el controlador, te quedaría de esta forma el objeto de Miembros Parroquiales

```
$miembros = Miembro_Parroquial::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->sector($sector)->etapa($etapa)->formacion($forma)->cargo($m_cargo)->get();
```